# gfortran: error trying to exec 'f951': execvp: No such file or directory

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, fortran, gfortran

I'm trying to compile a code found on the internet. Actually I'm trying to compile the code found at http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~fowlkes/BSE/.

I tried to install gfortran and all the other libraries that are needed for compiling it in my MAC. But when I run the command **make** I get the following error:

```
$ make
(cd trlan && make -f Makefile.gcc)
gfortran -O3 -ffixed-line-length-132 -c dsort2.f
gfortran: error trying to exec 'f951': execvp: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [dsort2.o] Error 1
make: *** [trlan/libtrlan.a] Error 2
```

I believed that the error is related to the version of my c++ compiler, that is not compatible with gfortran.

When I run the command **gcc --version**:

```
$ gcc --version
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
```

And when I run the command **gfortran --version**:

```
$ gfortran --version
GNU Fortran (GCC) 4.8.0 20120930 (experimental)
```

The Makefile under the directory that I'm running the command **make** is here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/q7mxvhnqg62ioum/Makefile.gcc

The Makefile under the directory trlan is here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jydwpkg3f1upbgf/Makefile.gcc

Anyone has an idea of how to solve this problem or how to find tools that can help me solve it?

I'm trying this:
http://eftrunk.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-to-fix-error-trying-to-exec-f951.html

Comment: See http://eftrunk.blogspot.co.uk/2011/11/how-to-fix-error-trying-to-exec-f951.html

Comment: Try the steps in the comment 3. It might help.
http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=33814

Answer (score 5):

The simplest solution I found (perhaps not cleanest), is to statically link f951 in the path to the binary of gfortran:

```
find /usr/local/ -name f951
```

which for me returned:

```
/usr/local/gfortran/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin11/4.6.2/f951
/usr/local/gfortran/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14/5.1.0/f951
```

so I put a link to the one that fits my system most closely in /usr/local/bin:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/gfortran/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14/5.1.0/f951 /usr/local/bin/.
```

And now gfortran works again. No need to uninstall XCode or any other exaggerated workload.

Comment: In my case I was just missing the gfortran itself. On debian install with `sudo apt install gfortran`.

Answer (score -3):

The answer can be found in the following website:

http://eftrunk.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-to-fix-error-trying-to-exec-f951.html

Basically it's necessary to delete Xcode, reinstall gcc and gfortran using http://hpc.sourceforge.net/ and then reinstall Xcode.

Comment: Website is not available anymore.