# How to use gfortran with NetBeans on OS X Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, fortran

I'm using Mountain Lion. I use gfortran from the Terminal. But I want to use it from IDE like NetBeans. When I want to use it like I do on Ubuntu it shows me an error-

```
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/hello_1
mkdir -p build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX
gfortran   -c -g -o build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/ab1.o ab1.F90
gfortran: error trying to exec 'f951': execvp: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** [build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/ab1.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 134ms)
```

How can i fix this problem. Is there any way to use fortran from a IDE like NetBeans??

Comment: Similar problem [previously posted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13293762/gfortran-error-trying-to-exec-f951-execvp-no-such-file-or-directory) with a solution [found here](http://eftrunk.blogspot.no/2011/11/how-to-fix-error-trying-to-exec-f951.html)