# Netbeans fortran build fails on Mac OS 10.8, cannot see gfortran file

Tags: netbeans, compiler-construction, fortran, binaries

I'm trying to get Netbeans up and running so I can start a Fortran project. I've downloaded the binaries and installed the plugins to the best of my knowledge. When I try to compile my hello world I get this error:

```
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/convection
mkdir -p build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX
gfortran   -c -g -o build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/main.o main.f
gfortran: error trying to exec 'f951': execvp: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** [build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/main.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2


BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 111ms)
```

Any thoughts?

EDIT: I'm using Mac OSX 10.8.5

EDIT 2: I've been messing around for awhile now and now the error is slightly different:

```
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/convection
mkdir -p build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX
gfortran   -c -g -o build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/main.o main.f
make[2]: gfortran: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** [build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/main.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2


BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 127ms)
```

EDIT 3: And just for fun, here is the output from a successful build that I was able to do in Ubuntu:

```
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/hannah/NetBeansProjects/test'
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/test
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/hannah/NetBeansProjects/test'
make[2]: `dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/test' is up to date.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/hannah/NetBeansProjects/test'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/hannah/NetBeansProjects/test' 

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 92ms)
```

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17885369/how-to-use-gfortran-with-netbeans-on-os-x-mountain-lion)

Comment: Can you compile `main.f` via terminal?

Comment: Good point. Yes I can compile and run via the terminal just fine.

Comment: Hmm. My best guess, then, is that Netbeans is not looking in the correct place for gfortran. Perhaps you can specify gfortran by it's path (i.e., `/usr/local/bin/gfortran`)?

Comment: Ya I've tried that too. It's now basically saying that the file "gfortran" does not exist when I'm telling it exactly where it is.

Comment: I've added a couple of edits up there that may or may not shed some light on something.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on 10.9. I needed to make a new gfortran link in my /usr/bin (Base directory). After that it worked fine. If I had it in usr/local/bin,..or any other path it didn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to someone else's solution to this problem.  gfortran is unable to find f951.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1164394

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this solution was to install the gfortran compiler, which I have already done.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution here: http://eftrunk.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-to-fix-error-trying-to-exec-f951.html

Will report back if it works or not.

Comment: Did you try what `jerdavis` said in the comments on that link?

Comment: I copied all the files, yes. Thanks for pointing that out though.