# Configuring gfortran compiler on NetBeans 8.2 on MacOS 10.14.3

Tags: gfortran, netbeans-8

I'm trying to run fortran code using NetBeans 8.2 on my Mac running MacOS 10.14.3 Mojave. I installed gcc using homebrew, and the compiler is found at /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/bin/gfortran. This is the error from NetBeans Console:

```
cd '/Users/david/Desktop/Computational/ComputationalHW'
/usr/bin/make -f Makefile CONF=Debug
"/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make" -f
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
"/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make"  -f
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/computationalhw
mkdir -p dist/Debug/GNU-MacOSX
gfortran    -o dist/Debug/GNUMacOSX/computationalhwbuild/Debug/GNUMacOSX/HW1.o 
make[2]: gfortran: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** [dist/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/computationalhw] Error 1
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 113ms)
```

Here's my configuration from NetBeans:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6qBG.png)

UPDATE: I have also tried this configuration, same error:

```
/usr/local/bin/gfortran
```

Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
One must simply add /usr/local/bin/ to $PATH on NetBeans. This resolves the issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Netbeans fortran build fails on Mac OS 10.8, cannot see gfortran file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19203622/2985643) though that question did not have an accepted answer. However, one answer stated _"I needed to make a new gfortran link in my /usr/bin (Base directory). After that it worked fine. If I had it in usr/local/bin,..or any other path it didn't work."_,  so perhaps that is worth trying.

Comment: Thanks, after following several links it became apparent that just adding /usr/local/bin to the $PATH config on NetBeans fixes it (DUH!). Apparently NetBeans doesn't look on that directory automatically. Issue has been resolved.

Comment: Cool. Based on your feedback, presumably the solution I referred to worked for that user because  `/usr/bin` was already on their $PATH.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll accept my own answer once StackOverflow allows me (need to wait some time...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out NetBeans does not look under /usr/local/bin even though you might declare your compiler to be directly underneath that directory. Therefore, it is necessary to add the /usr/local/bin option to the $PATH configuration.
[image]

On the Build Tools options in the settings on NetBeans, click on the $PATH button across Base Directory and under PATH = add the path to your own directory where your compiler is found.

Mine looks likes this:

```
${TOOLS_PATH};${PATH};/usr/local/bin
```

[image]