# Can not compile fortran 90 code in vscode in macOS Catalina using task.json

Tags: visual-studio-code, fortran, gfortran

I am trying to compile fortran 90 code using gfortran compiler in vscode in macOS Catalina. When I use the command, `gfortran -o ./main Hello.f90`, in vscode terminal, it works. However, if I try to add task.json and try to 'Run Task’ it throws an error. `gfortran: fatal error: cannot execute 'f951': execvp: No such file or directory compilation terminated.` I have tried several things including one with `find/usr/local/ -name f951` in this link [gfortran: error trying to exec 'f951': execvp: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13293762/gfortran-error-trying-to-exec-f951-execvp-no-such-file-or-directory), but no luck. Please help.

My task.json

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "gfortran",
            "args": [
                "-o",
                "./main",
                "Hello.f90"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]

}
```

Comment: Please use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortrsn questions. Your question is not specific to the very old Fortran 90 revision.

Comment: Ok, I will do that from next time.

Answer (score 0):

here is my task.json see if it helps you out. Mind the commented line ".exe". Maybe there you can paste the relevant extension for macOS.

```
{
// See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
// for the documentation about the tasks.json format    
"version": "2.0.0",
"_runner": "terminal",
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "build_gfortran",
        "type": "shell",
        "windows": {
            "command": "gfortran"
        },
        "linux": {
            "command": "gfortran"
        },
        "osx": {
            "command": "gfortran"
        },
        "args": [
            "${file}",
            "-g",
            "-o",
        // "${workspaceRoot}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            "${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
        ],
        "problemMatcher": [],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        }
     }
  ]
}
```

BTW, very first time posting in here.
Cheers.